# Turn ON/OFF Webcam using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, webcam

I'm using [`webcam`](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive) directive for capturing photos. I'm able to turn OFF the camera. But I'm not able ON it again. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current code to stop the camera.

```
var mStream = null;

$scope.onStream = function (stream) {
    // You could do something manually with the stream.
    mStream = stream;
};
$scope.stopCamera = function() {
    // mStream.stop();  didn't work.
    mStream.getTracks()[0].stop();
};
$scope.startCamera = function() {
    // mStream.play(); didn't work
    // ToDo
};
```

Thank you

Comment: **control readyState and set track.enabled=false**
       


`mStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {

                if (track.readyState == 'live') {

                track.stop();

                track.enabled = false;

                 }

            });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [webcam](https://github.com/jonashartmann/webcam-directive) directive we have following events

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', onDestroy);
$scope.$on('START_WEBCAM', startWebcam);
$scope.$on('STOP_WEBCAM', stopWebcam);
```

in your controller you can use something like this

```
  $scope.destroyWebcam = function () {
    $scope.$broadcast('$destroy');
  };

 $scope.stopWebcam = function () {
   $scope.$broadcast('STOP_WEBCAM');
 };
```

Comment: Thank a lot. One more question. A user have two cameras. How can I list available camera's and select a specific camera?

Comment: @SGG i am not sure but you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893787/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-video-cameras-attached-in-my-computer-using-javascript

Comment: When I used the `stop_webcam` the video stream disappeared but the red circle at the tab is still there and the LED of my webcam is still ON. All the same even if I already went to another page on my website. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @JkAlombro, I have the same problem :/