# I am unable to get show different devices both audio and video available during stream

Tags: javascript

I was just going through https://github.com/ScaleDrone/webrtc/blob/master/script.js but there is no way i could select from the devices and stream

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: true,
  }).then(stream => {
    // Display your local video in #localVideo element
    localVideo.srcObject = stream;
    // Add your stream to be sent to the conneting peer
    stream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc.addTrack(track, stream));
  }, onError);
```

how do i get all the device id shown for both video as well as audio source . please helpp me anyone

i just want that all device id should be shown and i can select any one from them.

I actually mean to say that when i use this on my phone it only selects my front camera . but what command should i insert here so that i can move to my rear camera or any other camera device attached and same is the case of audio, there are no audio devices to select from

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893787/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-video-cameras-attached-in-my-computer-using-javascript) may answer you question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [enumerateMediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices) it seems to be implemented on all recent browsers (Not IE).