# How can I access the system built-in camera, among multiple virtual cameras, through Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a feature in my project where I have installed multiple virtual cameras on my system, but I need to detect the original camera among them. I am using VueJs for this task.

After extensive research, I found that JavaScript provides a way to access the user's enabled camera using the mediaDevices API, and I am able to retrieve its device id and label. However, I need to access the system's built-in camera, which can be done using Python or Java. Unfortunately, I have not found any other way to do this in VueJs.

I have searched a lot but could not found any solution.
[My current enabled camera device id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvbFd.png)
I am getting it by using this code:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then((stream) => {
               const enabledDeviceId = stream.getTracks().map(track => track.getSettings().deviceId);
});
```

Comment: It's irrelevant to Vue. Consider explaining why it worked for you in Python or Java but not JS. I doubt it's possible, unless you can deduce it from a label.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893787/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-video-cameras-attached-in-my-computer-using-javascript) help?

Comment: If I look at Python, it provides the OpenCV library to access the system's built-in camera. However, if I want to access the camera in Vue.js, how can I do it? Please give me a solution for accessing the system's built-in camera using JS. as VueJs is a javascript framework.

Comment: But if I hardcode the label check, it is a poor solution because if I run that code on another system like Mac or Windows, both of which have different built-in camera labels, the code will break.

Comment: I think there must be a generic way to obtain the system's camera device ID or label.

Comment: *must be a way to obtain the camera label*" - yes, using the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399845/2181514

Comment: Thanks Freedomn-m for the solution, but I have already obtained an array of all cameras connected to my device, including my built-in camera. However, how can I identify, among the array values, which one is my system's default camera?

Comment: Default and built-in are not the same thing. (Windows let you configure a default camera, my phone has two built-in cameras, my desktop doesn't have a built-in camera).

Comment: Yes you are right, default and built-in cameras are not same. I get the default camera device id but I need built-in camera. Basically in my project, the requirement is to allow user to only use system built-in camera if he try to use some other camera instead of built-in I want to redirect him back. So, what should I do now? How I could resolve this???

Comment: please anyone help me to resolve it

Comment: If I do it using web assembling the python code in javascript how it will be done ??